# Angular MatTable does not update with data that comes from a Form

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material

I'm just learning Angular (actually started to learn web development a few months ago). I want to display data from a Form into a table. I have the following model:

```
export class Content {

    id: number = 0;
    title?: string;
    subtitle?: string;
    content?: string;
    date?: string;
    media?: string;
}
```

Then, I have a form with some methods as `onSubmit()` that pushes data into an array.

```
onSubmit() {
    if (this.selectedContent.id === 0) {
        this.selectedContent.id = this.contentsList.length + 1;
        this.contentsList.push(this.selectedContent);
    }

    this.selectedContent = new Content();
    this.notificationService.success('El postulante se creó correctamente');
    console.log(this.contentsList);
}
```

When I console.log `contentsList` it shows with the new data from the form, but it does not show in the table:

```
dataSource = this.contentsList;
columnsToDisplay = ['title', 'subtitle', 'body', 'date'];
expandedElement: Content | null | undefined;
```

This is my table:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let content"> {{content[column]}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <!-- Expanded Content Column - The detail row is made up of this one column that spans across all columns -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element[attr.colspan]="columnsToDisplay.length">
            <div class="example-element-detail" [@detailExpand]="element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
                <div class="example-element-diagram">
                    <div class="example-element-position"> {{content.title}} </div>
                    <div class="example-element-symbol"> {{content.subtitle}} </div>
                    <div class="example-element-name"> {{content.date}} </div>
                    <div class="example-element-weight"> {{content.body}} </div>
                </div>
                <div class="example-element-description">
                  {{content.body}}
                  <span class="example-element-description-attribution"> </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let content; columns: columnsToDisplay;"
      class="example-element-row" [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === content" (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === content ? null : content">
    </tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="example-detail-row"></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has no about changeDetectorRef. the problem with a MatTable is that if we add/remove/change an element of the datasource we need say that redraw the table again See the docs, in the [API about DataSource](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api)

> If a data array is provided, the table must be notified when the array's objects are added, removed, or moved. This can be done by calling the renderRows() function which will render the diff since the last table render. If the data array reference is changed, the table will automatically trigger an update to the rows

So, if you only has one table in your component you can use ViewChild to get the table

```
@ViewChild(MatTable) table:MatTable<any>
```

So, when you add the element you use `this.table.renderRows()`.

```
if (this.selectedContent.id === 0) {
    ...
    this.table.renderRows()
}
```

But you need take account another thing in your code. You use

```
//the code is WRONG
if (this.selectedContent.id === 0) {
  this.contentsList.push(this.selectedContent);
}
this.selectedContent = new Content();
```

Is wrong because you are adding the same "object", you need make a "copy" of the object. If your object is a simple object, this copy can be make it using the spreadOperator, so the function becomes finally like

```
onSubmit() {
    if (this.selectedContent.id === 0) {
      this.selectedContent.id = this.contentsList.length + 1;
      //push a "copy of the object
      this.contentsList.push({...this.selectedContent});
      this.table.renderRows()
    }
    this.selectedContent = new Content();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpfull. That was actually my problem, and now with the renderRows() method it is solved. And I also thank you for that insight about my code; i did not know about the spread operator.

Answer (score -1):

It might be you have used `changeDetection` method in your component.
Please look at your ts file if you have `ChangeDetectionStrategy`
This is the example code.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    templateUrl: './test.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['test.component.scss'],
})
```

If you have change detection then there are two ways to fix this issue.

1. Simply remove the below line from your component ts file.

   `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`
2. Please add the below code to your ts component file.

Import ChangeDetectorRef at the top of the ts file.

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

Add a reference to the constructor.

```
constructor(public changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
```

Add below the line at the end of `onSubmit` method.

```
this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
```

Comment: Sorry, the problem has no about changeDetectorRef.