# Angular mat table

Tags: angular

I am trying to delete a record from a table which I have created using angular material -

I delete a record from this table but my view does not get refreshed, even though record is deleted.

HTML code -

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="delete">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Delete </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let i = index">
          <button mat-button class="mat-icon-btn-ripple"  (click)="deleteAlert(element.id, i)">
            <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </td>
 </ng-container>
```

this.dataSource.data.splice(i,1);

How shall I get updated view of datasource?

Answer (score 0):

The view does not get updated because the array is still *the same*. You are mutating the data source instead of changing it. Angular change detection assumes the data is unchanged, unless you do something like this:

```
// use the spread operator to create a new array instance
// containing the same elements as dataSource.data
const data = [...this.dataSource.data];
// remove the item in the newly created array
data.splice(i, 1);
// assign the new array instance to the dataSource.data property
this.dataSource.data = data;
```

Comment: Another approach it's use `renderRows()`, see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69632939/angular-mattable-does-not-update-with-data-that-comes-from-a-form/69636815#69636815)

Comment: When I create new table, it refresh the page but it navigates back to the first page.