# Angular material mat-table delete selected row

Tags: angular, material-table, angular-material-table

I want to delete the angular mat table selected row, can you help with that?

Delete the row using a button placed outside of the table instead of using a delete button on each row of the table.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84bPI.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to achieve what you want,

- Save the index of the row.
- When delete is clicked splice the data source and re-render the rows.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;

  selectedItemIdx = null;

  @ViewChild(MatTable) table:MatTable<any>

  rowSelected(selectedItemIdx) {
    this.selectedItemIdx = selectedItemIdx;
  }

  deleteSelected() {
    this.dataSource.splice(this.selectedItemIdx, 1);
    this.table.renderRows()
    this.selectedItemIdx = null;
  }
}
```

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  ...
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let i = index" (click)=rowSelected(i) [ngClass]="{'highlight': i === selectedItemIdx}"></tr>
</table>


<button (click)="deleteSelected()">Delete</button>
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: better than create a new array using spread, you can get the mat-table using `@ViewChild(MatTable) table:MatTable<any>`and use `this.table.renderRows()`. explained in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69632939/angular-mattable-does-not-update-with-data-that-comes-from-a-form/69636815#69636815)

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GILje.png)

```js
import { SelectionModel } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { Component, HostListener, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTable, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { WebApiService } from 'src/app/service/web-api.service';
import { __values } from 'tslib';
import { StokKayitComponent } from './dialog/stok-kayit/stok-kayit.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-stok',
  templateUrl: './stok.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stok.component.css']  
})
export class StokComponent implements OnInit
{
  stokList!:Observable<any[]>; 
  
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id','grupKodu', 'sicilKodu', 'sicilAdi','action'];
  dataSource!: MatTableDataSource<any>;
  selection = new SelectionModel<Element>(true, []);
  element:any;
  selectedItemIdx = null;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatTable) table!: MatTable<any>;
  
  rowSelected(selectedItemIdx: null) {
    this.selectedItemIdx = selectedItemIdx;
  }
  
  deleteSelected() 
  {
    this.element.splice(this.selectedItemIdx, 1);
    this.table.renderRows()
    this.selectedItemIdx = null;
  }

  
  @HostListener('window:keyup.esc') onKeyUp() {this.dialog.closeAll();}  // ESC tuşu ile sayfadan çıkış yapar.

  // Yabancı anahtarlarla ilişkili verileri görüntülemek için harita
  stokListMap:Map<number, string> = new Map();  
  clickedRows = new Set<PeriodicWave>();    
  
  
  constructor(private service:WebApiService, public dialog:MatDialog) { }

  openDialog(): void // dialog stok kayıt formuna gider. 
  {
    this.dialog.open (StokKayitComponent, 
      {
        autoFocus:false,
        width:'1200px',
        height:'750px',
        panelClass:"custom", // MAT-DIALOG border-radius ayarları.
        disableClose:true, //Diyalog alanının dışına tıklamayı devre dışı bırakır.
        backdropClass:"blurBackground" //MAT-DIALOG açıldığında arkaplanı blur yapar.
      }      
    );
  }
 

  ngOnInit(): void 
  {    
    this.stokList = this.service.getStokListesi();
    this.service.getStokListesi().subscribe
    (
      res =>
      {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res);
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      }
    )        
  }    
  
  applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }

  deleteRow(id:number)
  {
    this.service.delete(id)    
    .subscribe({
      next:(res)=> 
      {
        alert("Sicil Silindi.");
        this.service.getStokListesi()
        .subscribe
          (
            res =>
              {
                this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res);
                this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
                this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
              }
          )     
        
      },
      error:()=>
      {
        alert("Hata! Sicil Silinemedi.")
      }
    })
  } 

 
}
```

```css
#container
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: #00c6ff;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #0072ff, #00c6ff);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #0072ff, #00c6ff); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
    
}

/*login panel start*/
.kayit-panel
{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;        
}

.mat-table
{
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.example-spacer
{
  flex: 1 1 auto;  
}

.mat-toolbar 
{
  background-color: white;  
  border-top-left-radius:30px;
  border-top-right-radius:30px;
  gap: 8px;
}


.login-giris-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  padding: 50px;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

/*login panel end*/

.gorev-cubugu
{
    position: absolute;
    flex-direction: column;
    right: 20px;
    top: 15px;
}

.login-baslik
{
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;  
}

.giris-yap
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.mat-raised-button
{
  height: 40px;  
  border-radius: 10px;  
}


table 
{
  width: 100%;  
}

.div-table
{  
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 550px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  max-height: 680px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: white;
}

.mat-form-field {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100%;
}

.login-kayit-container
{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 1500px;
  max-height: 750px;  
}

.icerik
{  
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 1500px;
  height: 750px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.fonksiyon
{ 
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  height: 99px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  bottom: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:30px;
}

.paginator
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 217px;
  width: 100%;   
  text-align: center;  
}

.araclar
{
  
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 98px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}

.butonlar
{
  display:flex;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  gap:10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:30px;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding: 10px;  
}

.mat-row .mat-cell 
{  
  cursor: pointer;  
}

.mat-row:hover .mat-cell
{  
  background:#ff4081;
  color: white;
}

.demo-row-is-clicked
{
  font-weight: bold;
  background:#fa0404;
  color: #F5F5F5;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div class="kayit-panel">
      <div class="login-kayit-container">      
        <div class="icerik">

          <mat-toolbar class="mat-elevation-z8">            
            <span><mat-icon></mat-icon>ANA KATALOG STOK İŞLEMLERİ</span>
            <span class="example-spacer"></span>
            <button mat-mini-fab color="warn"><mat-icon>question_mark</mat-icon></button>
            <button routerLink="/erp" mat-mini-fab><mat-icon>close</mat-icon></button>
          </mat-toolbar>
          <!--<div class="gorev-cubugu"><button routerLink="/erp" mat-mini-fab aria-label="Example icon button with a menu icon"><mat-icon>close</mat-icon></button></div>-->
          <!---  içerik gelecek-->                 
          <table mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" matSort>

            <!-- Name Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ID </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" Width='100px'> {{element.id}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <!-- Name Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="grupKodu">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> GURUP KODU </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" Width='150px'> {{element.grupKodu}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <!-- Weight Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="sicilKodu">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> SİCİL KODU </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" Width='150px'> {{element.sicilKodu}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <!-- Symbol Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="sicilAdi">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> SİCİL ADI </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" Width='500px'> {{element.sicilAdi}} </td>              
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Action </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                <button mat-mini-fab color="warn" aria-label="Example icon button with a filter list icon" (click)="deleteRow(element.id)"><mat-icon>delete</mat-icon></button>
              </td>              
            </ng-container>

            <tr mat-header-row style="height: 50px;" *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
            
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let i = index" (click)=rowSelected(i) [ngClass]="{'highlight': i === selectedItemIdx}"></tr>            
            <!-- Row shown when there is no matching data. -->
            <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow><td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">"{{input.value}}" Ürün bulunamadı! </td></tr>
          </table>

           <!-- Tablo Sayfalama -->
          <div class="paginator mat-elevation-z8"><mat-paginator style="background-color: white;" [pageSizeOptions]="[12]" showFirstLastButtons aria-label="Select page of periodic elements"></mat-paginator></div>
          <div class="araclar">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
              <mat-label>ÜRÜN ARA</mat-label>
              <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event)" placeholder="Sicil Kodu, Sicil Adı, Grup kodu vb..." #input>
              <mat-hint>Ürün Arama</mat-hint>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>

          <div class="fonksiyon mat-elevation-z8">                        
            <div class="butonlar">
              <button style="width:200px;" mat-raised-button color="accent" type="submit" routerLink="/kayit"><mat-icon>save</mat-icon> Kayıt</button>
              <button style="width:200px;" mat-raised-button color="accent" type="submit" (click)="openDialog()"> <mat-icon>change_circle</mat-icon> Değiştir</button>
              <button style="width:200px;" mat-raised-button color="accent" type="submit" (click)="deleteSelected()"><mat-icon>delete</mat-icon> Sil</button>
            </div>            
          </div>          
        </div>              
      </div>    
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: this.datasource.splice not this.element.splice, copy the deleteSelected code from the answer and try

Answer (score 0):

you have tu use the tabel with selection

https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-selection

And you have to add the delete function, like this

https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-dynamic-array-data

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Stash

I did what you said. It didn't happen. If I give you the codes, would you edit and send them to me?

Only then can I understand.

```js
import { SelectionModel } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { Component, HostListener, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTable, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { WebApiService } from 'src/app/service/web-api.service';
import { __values } from 'tslib';
import { StokKayitComponent } from './dialog/stok-kayit/stok-kayit.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-stok',
  templateUrl: './stok.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stok.component.css']  
})
export class StokComponent implements OnInit
{
  stokList!:Observable<any[]>; 
  
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id','grupKodu', 'sicilKodu', 'sicilAdi','action'];  
  dataSource!: MatTableDataSource<any>;
  selection = new SelectionModel<Element>(true, []);
  element:any;
    
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;  
  @HostListener('window:keyup.esc') onKeyUp() {this.dialog.closeAll();}  // ESC tuşu ile sayfadan çıkış yapar.

 
  // Yabancı anahtarlarla ilişkili verileri görüntülemek için harita
  stokListMap:Map<number, string> = new Map();  
  clickedRows = new Set<PeriodicWave>();    
  
  
  constructor(private service:WebApiService, public dialog:MatDialog) { }

  openDialog(): void // dialog stok kayıt formuna gider. 
  {
    this.dialog.open (StokKayitComponent, 
      {
        autoFocus:false,
        width:'1200px',
        height:'750px',
        panelClass:"custom", // MAT-DIALOG border-radius ayarları.
        disableClose:true, //Diyalog alanının dışına tıklamayı devre dışı bırakır.
        backdropClass:"blurBackground" //MAT-DIALOG açıldığında arkaplanı blur yapar.
      }      
    );
  }
 

  ngOnInit(): void 
  {    
    this.stokList = this.service.getStokListesi();
    this.service.getStokListesi().subscribe
    (
      res =>
      {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res);
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      }
    )        
  }    
  
  applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }

  deleteRow(id:number)
  {
    this.service.delete(id)    
    .subscribe({
      next:(res)=> 
      {
        alert("Sicil Silindi.");
        this.service.getStokListesi()
        .subscribe
          (
            res =>
              {
                this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res);
                this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
                this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
              }
          )     
        
      },
      error:()=>
      {
        alert("Hata! Sicil Silinemedi.")
      }
    })
  }
  
  

 
}
```

```css
#container
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: #00c6ff;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #0072ff, #00c6ff);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #0072ff, #00c6ff); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
    
}

/*login panel start*/
.kayit-panel
{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;        
}

.mat-table
{
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.example-spacer
{
  flex: 1 1 auto;  
}

.mat-toolbar 
{
  background-color: white;  
  border-top-left-radius:30px;
  border-top-right-radius:30px;
  gap: 8px;
}


.login-giris-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  padding: 50px;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

/*login panel end*/

.gorev-cubugu
{
    position: absolute;
    flex-direction: column;
    right: 20px;
    top: 15px;
}

.login-baslik
{
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;  
}

.giris-yap
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.mat-raised-button
{
  height: 40px;  
  border-radius: 10px;  
}


table 
{
  width: 100%;  
}

.div-table
{  
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 550px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  max-height: 680px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: white;
}

.mat-form-field {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100%;
}

.login-kayit-container
{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 1500px;
  max-height: 750px;  
}

.icerik
{  
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 1500px;
  height: 750px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.fonksiyon
{ 
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  height: 99px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  bottom: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:30px;
}

.paginator
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 217px;
  width: 100%;   
  text-align: center;  
}

.araclar
{
  
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 98px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}

.butonlar
{
  display:flex;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  gap:10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:30px;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding: 10px;  
}

.mat-row .mat-cell 
{  
  cursor: pointer;  
}

.mat-row:hover .mat-cell
{  
  background:#ff4081;
  color: white;
}

.demo-row-is-clicked
{
  font-weight: bold;
  background:#fa0404;
  color: #F5F5F5;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="kayit-panel">
      <div class="login-kayit-container">      
        <div class="icerik">

          <mat-toolbar class="mat-elevation-z8">            
            <span><mat-icon></mat-icon>ANA KATALOG STOK İŞLEMLERİ</span>
            <span class="example-spacer"></span>
            <button mat-mini-fab color="warn"><mat-icon>question_mark</mat-icon></button>
            <button routerLink="/erp" mat-mini-fab><mat-icon>close</mat-icon></button>
          </mat-toolbar>
          <!--<div class="gorev-cubugu"><button routerLink="/erp" mat-mini-fab aria-label="Example icon button with a menu icon"><mat-icon>close</mat-icon></button></div>-->
          <!---  içerik gelecek-->                 
          <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" matSort>
          
            <!-- Name Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ID </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" Width='100px'> {{element.id}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <!-- Name Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="grupKodu">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> GURUP KODU </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" Width='150px'> {{element.grupKodu}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <!-- Weight Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="sicilKodu">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> SİCİL KODU </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" Width='150px'> {{element.sicilKodu}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <!-- Symbol Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="sicilAdi">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> SİCİL ADI </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" Width='500px'> {{element.sicilAdi}} </td>              
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Action </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                <button mat-mini-fab color="warn" aria-label="Example icon button with a filter list icon" (click)="deleteRow(element.id)"><mat-icon>delete</mat-icon></button>
              </td>              
            </ng-container>

            <tr mat-header-row style="height: 50px;" *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>

            <tr mat-row style="height: 30px;" (click)="clickedRows.add(row)" [class.demo-row-is-clicked]="clickedRows.has(row)" *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>            
            <!-- Row shown when there is no matching data. -->
            <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow><td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">"{{input.value}}" Ürün bulunamadı! </td></tr>
          </table>

           <!-- Tablo Sayfalama -->
          <div class="paginator mat-elevation-z8"><mat-paginator style="background-color: white;" [pageSizeOptions]="[12]" showFirstLastButtons aria-label="Select page of periodic elements"></mat-paginator></div>
          <div class="araclar">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
              <mat-label>ÜRÜN ARA</mat-label>
              <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event)" placeholder="Sicil Kodu, Sicil Adı, Grup kodu vb..." #input>
              <mat-hint>Ürün Arama</mat-hint>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>

          <div class="fonksiyon mat-elevation-z8">                        
            <div class="butonlar">
              <button style="width:200px;" mat-raised-button color="accent" type="submit" routerLink="/kayit"><mat-icon>save</mat-icon> Kayıt</button>
              <button style="width:200px;" mat-raised-button color="accent" type="submit" (click)="openDialog()"> <mat-icon>change_circle</mat-icon> Değiştir</button>
              <button style="width:200px;" mat-raised-button color="accent" type="submit"><mat-icon>delete</mat-icon> Sil</button>
            </div>            
          </div>          
        </div>              
      </div>    
    </div>  
</div>
```